# AutoNew macro not working

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to get Word to open an Excel document whenever a document based on a specific template is created.

Here is my macro

```
Sub AutoNew()
Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Workbook
Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("E:\Letters.xlsx")
End Sub
```

When I double-click the template, it brings up a document based on the template just fine, but the macro doesn't run.

It shows up in the list of macros in the template, but attempting to run it doesn't do anything.

Comment: your excel file is opened in the background, did you check if new Excel instance is not running which you can't see? to see it you could add this line: `oExcel.Visible = true`

Comment: Always the small things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has mentioned KazJaw, make app visible

```
Sub AutoNew()
  Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
  Dim oWB As Workbook
  Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
  Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("E:\Letters.xlsx")
  oExcel.Visible = true
End Sub
```

A disadvantage is, that excel application is launching as a new task (see tak manager) in case of another calling the macro - every document is opened in its own task.

The correct way is use API for launching a document in registered application, for example here: http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0018.htm

Or one-row workaround, ugly, but works great:

```
Shell "cmd.exe /c start D:\a\test.xlsx"
```

Note that template with macro must have extension .xltm, not .xltx.